# aws s3 boto3 copy()

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to execute the following program and facing this issue

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling
>   the HeadObject operation: Not Found

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'forw',
    'Key': 'test'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source,Bucket='copybucket0526',Key='tet')
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. What do you want to achieve? What exactly is it you are asking?

Comment: Have you created both buckets and keys?

Comment: Do you have a bucket called `forw` that contains an object called `test`?

Comment: It is working Thank you

Comment: Typical boto3 newbie mistake of declare boto3 s3 service resources and then use the low level service client `s3.meta.client.copy` .  (or is it came from one of the bad AWS boto3 documentation example)

Comment: @mootmoot bad boto3 documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it will work

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'source_bucket',
    'Key': 'dirname/subdirname/filename.gz'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source,Bucket='destination_bucket',Key='somedirname/new_or_same_filename.gz')
```

This is working I guess you are wrong in providing the path, means here you need to provide file complete path

Answer (score 0):

In general a 404 code on HeadObject means that the resource does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

in the place of key make sure the you are taking care of parent folder or sub directories(if any) of the file you are going to copy from the source bucket.

```
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'forw',
    'Key': 'top_directory/sub_directory/file.jpg'
}
```