# Why is boto3 silently failing when copying one file from one S3 bucket to another?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use boto3 in Python3 to copy a file from one S3 bucket to another. I have seen the following,

- [Move files between two AWS S3 buckets using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161700/move-files-between-two-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3)
- [boto3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy)
- [aws s3 boto3 copy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315867/aws-s3-boto3-copy)
- [How to write a file or data to an S3 object using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336918/how-to-write-a-file-or-data-to-an-s3-object-using-boto3)

My code is as follows.

```
import boto3

bucket_old = "bold" # old bucket name
key_old =  "/k/old" # old file key

bucket_new = "bnew"  # new bucket name
key_new = "/k/new"  # new file key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': bucket_old,
    'Key': key_old
}

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': bucket_old,
    'Key': key_old
}

print(copy_source)
print(bucket_new+key_new)
response = s3.meta.client.copy(CopySource=copy_source, Bucket=bucket_new, Key=key_new)
print(response)
print("done")
```

As I understand it, this is exactly what the docs suggest. I have tried it with and without the arg names in the `copy` command.

Both the `print(bucket_new+key_new)` and `print("done")` lines execute as expected, and the program completes successfully. Unfortunately, however, the file does not appear in the new location. It would appear that the `copy` itself is silently failing. Additionally, `response` returns `None`. What could be causing these?

I can successfully list all buckets with

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

This suggests that I have successfully authenticated onto the AWS account.

What am I missing here? Is `s3.meta.client.copy` the right approach, or should I use `copy_object`? What is the difference between these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setting keys with a leading `/` causes boto3 to fail silently in this scenario. Remove the leading `/`.